# Adding associated value by not using foreign key in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Recently I've started using CakePHP by starting from using Bake to get simple CRUD.

I have one Model called "Contract" which is associated with "Product" and "Customer" as following.

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
    'Customer' => array(
        'className' => 'Customer',
        'foreignKey' => 'customer_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Product' => array(
        'className' => 'Product',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Now I wanted to customize the add view (add.ctp) created by Bake by not using select box as an input form for customer_id and product_id. Instead of using select box which shows all the possible name of product/customer that are associated with foreign key I want to use text field so that people can type in one of the field (for example product_code, customer_code) from Product / Customer table and convert it to foreign key to create a row for Contract table. In case there is a chance that no values be found from Customer / Product field I want to skip adding a row to Contract table.

I would like to know if this is possible.

Thank you,

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Using the Product model as an example: create the text field, then in your controller try to find the primary key of the Product model using the value of the text field. If no id is returned, then don't save the Contract model.

Comment: Impossible is Nothing ™   ...you'll probably get better answers when you make your question more about the actual problem that you are facing, and less asking for a yes or no.

Comment: @ndm he asks to get the code written for him for an autocomplete on a text field that on select sets the id for the record.

Comment: @burzum I got that so far, that's why I was handing out broad hints :)

Answer (score 0):

The basic concept is this: Use a JS lib of your choice, guess it's jquery. Watch the text field for changes, on change make an ajax GET request with the value of the text field to a controller / action of your app [that returns json](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html). On click on one of the results set the id of the selected record to a hidden field. Done.

If you search Google or Stackoverflow you'll find plenty of examples.